# How to know when the focus is lost in a react native textInput?

Tags: javascript, react-native, focus

How to know when the focus is lost in a react native textInput?

For example I want to do an action when the user touches outside the textInput and it loses focus.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The prop you are looking for is the [onBlur](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onblur). This is called when it loses focus.

Answer (score 74):

use the `onBlur` prop on  `TextInput`

example

```
<TextInput
          onFocus={() =>console.log("focus received" ) }
          onBlur={() => console.log("focus lost") } />
```

[Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onblur)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onBlur prop on TextInput.

example

```
onBlurMethod = () =>{
   //what you want to do when it is not focused

}

<TextInput
         onBlur = {this.onBlurMethod}
/>
```